# Entity Framework 6 partial primary key auto-incrementing

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I am trying to make auto-increment key generation for only a part of the key for the given class:

```
class MyEntity
{
    [Key]
    public int OtherEntityId { get; set; }
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int MyEntityId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("OtherEntityId")]
    public virtual OtherEntity OtherEntity { get; set; }
}
```

So my issue with this is the auto generated keys dont start from 1 for each OtherEntityId.

What i mean is this is how my table looks after inserting some values:

```
| OtherEntityId | MyEntityId |
|      1        |      1     |
|      1        |      2     |
|      1        |      3     |
|      2        |      4     |
```

And i would expect the last row to be (2,1) instead of (2,4)

Is there a way to make this work with EF?

Comment: Your requirement differs from the `Identity` Idea, it is somehow related to `Sequence`. You might need to add a separate table to store the different values of the `OtherEntityId` and the corresponding `Sequence` value

Answer (score 0):

> And i would expect the last row to be (2,1) instead of (2,4) Is there

Why would you expect that.  The database would have to maintain a separate sequence/identity value for every one of your leading key values.

> a way to make this work with EF?

It already *works*.  You shouldn't worry about the actual number used in the trailing key value.  They will still be in order.  And there's no simple way in EF/SQL Server to generate the keys like you expect.  You'd have to start a transaction, take an exclusive lock on the leading key value while querying the existing max value for the key, insert the rows, and then commit.